# How to set where user is redirected to after logging in at wp-login?

Tags: wp-admin, wp-login-form, user-roles

So i'm fairly certain this probably has something to do with the fact that I'm using a custom role I've set up in my functions.php file with almost 0 permissions.  However, I'm still able to access the dashboard, just I get sent to profile.php on login instead of dashboard.  I want my user_role to get sent to the dashboard each time as I have a custom widget set up for them there.  I can't seem to find the function in the codex and the necessary hook to set this up?  It looks like if I was using a custom login form I could use `wp_login_form()` but I just want to use the default login form without hacking the admin file so its not effected by updates.  Anyone know the function I'm needing.  Cant' seem to feed google the right terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter `'login_redirect'`.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'wp_login', 'wpse_78150_login_redirect' );

function wpse_78150_login_redirect( $url )
{
    # uncomment the next line for debugging
    # var_dump( wp_get_current_user() ); exit;

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'custom_role' ) )
        return $url;

    return admin_url();
}
```

Comment: when I log in with my custom role I'm still being taken to profile.php.  I was supposed to substitute the name of my custom role for 'custom_role' correct?

Comment: @JohnB Yes, that should do the trick. I have added a debug helper to my suggestion. Try it, and add the result to your question.

Comment: WEll when I var_dump(! current_user_can( 'Coach' ), $url); exit; I'm getting true and ....myurl..../wp-admin/  but when it comes up false it goes to wp-admin/index.php.  I'm beginning to wonder if its possibly redirecting to profile.php after hitting index.php

Comment: yeah it was something else.  Now it works.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey @JohnB, What was that something else, if you can remember it. I'm having a similar issue where when I do a complete cold login, my user gets sent to the profile page using the above code. When the user is already logged in and then I hit the login screen again and log in, it takes me to the desired page. Any thoughts?

Comment: For anyone else: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect  "Note that the $current_user global may not be available at the time this filter is run. So you should use the $user global or the $user parameter passed to this filter. " So the use of current_user_can() appears to be the bug.

Comment: @Brent  hey brent, this is what worked for me in the end.  use the filter 'wp_login' instead of 'login_redirect'.  I'll edit the answer.  Your contribution is probably right as well.  I haven't worked on the project I used this on in a while though so I can't confirm.

Comment: Thanks @JohnB. I ended up using the solution in the codex, but this helps to flesh out other possible options. Thank you!